# How to get the m3u8 playlist from a iframe embed tag

Tags: android, kotlin

i have the following html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body >
   <iframe id="pic" src="http://rtsp.me/embed/883assBN/" width="450" height="254" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads there is a play button that when it is pressed it starts playing a video. When it is pressed on the chrome network tab there is a GET request with the following URL : " https://frn.rtsp.me/xAbXuzHiF6P3Hi8P7fK4_A/1598176697/hls/883assBN.m3u8 " .
The problem is after /frn.rtsp.me the sentences are being dynamically changed over some period of time for example :

```
https://frn.rtsp.me/XXX/XXX/hls/883assBN.m3u8
```

and i cannot obtain the new ones without using the provided html code and check the get requests in Chrome. My goal is to play the m3u8 video in a exoplayer on a Android device and what is the best way to view the get requests there from a webView or is there any other way to obtain the m3u8 playlist?

Best regards!

Comment: You can use Jsoup for parsing html sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone else is facing a similar issue here is my solution:

```
val embedUrl = "https://rtsp.me/embed/883assBN/"
try {
    val html: Connection.Response = Jsoup.connect(embedUrl).execute()
    val statusCode = html.statusCode()
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        val dok: Document = Jsoup.parse(html.body(), embedUrl)

        val scripts : Elements = dok.getElementsByTag("script")
        val urlScript : String = scripts.last().toString()
        val start_idx = urlScript.indexOf("https://")
        val end_idx = urlScript.indexOf(";")
        var tmp = urlScript.substring(start_idx,end_idx)
        val result =  tmp.replace("\"","")


    }

} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()

}
```